# Is there a way to identify points coming from specific normal distribution from a pool of points belonging to different normal distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, data-analysis

Suppose I have a pool of $n$ data points coming from different normal distributions. I know that there are $m_1$ many points generated from $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ distribution, $m_2$ many points from $N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ and so on ($\sum m_i=n$). However, I don't know which points they are as the dataset is mixed. Is there any statistical technique I can explore that may help me to identify all points coming from $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$?

Comment: When $\mu_1$ & $\mu_2$ have a "large gap" , there will be a Point $X$ between these two where the likelihoods are Equal. Points $<X$ will belong to Distribution 1. Points $>X$ will belong to Distribution 2. That is the best we can get. It is the 2-Class Classification Situation.

Comment: This approach is known as [quadratic discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_classifier#Quadratic_discriminant_analysis).

Comment: Are $m_i$, $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ all known?

Comment: @user51547 Yes, $m_i,\mu_i,\sigma_i$ are al known

Comment: @Adam Thanks; I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i$ be the $i^{th}$ data point and let $z_i=1$ if $x_i$ came from $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $z_i=0$ if it came from $N(\mu_0, \sigma_0^2)$, where the $z_i$ are unknown.

If we use a uniform prior over all possible valid $z=(z_1,\dots,z_n)$, i.e. $p(z)\propto \mathbb{1}\{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i = m_1\}$, then we can find the [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) estimate via maximizing the posterior distribution over $z$:

\begin{align*}
\log P(z\vert x)
&=\log P(x\vert z)\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2\sigma_{z_i}^2}\left(x_i-\mu_{z_i}\right)^2+ \frac{m_0}{2}\log 2\pi \sigma_{0}^2+ \frac{m_1}{2}\log 2\pi \sigma_{1}^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n z_i\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma_{1}^2}\left(x_i-\mu_{1}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{0}^2}\left(x_i-\mu_{0}\right)^2\right)+C
\end{align*}

subject to the constraint that $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i=m_1$ (for some constant $C$).

To solve, we just need to sort the $x_i$ according to $\Delta_i = \frac{1}{2\sigma_{1}^2}\left(x_i-\mu_{1}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{0}^2}\left(x_i-\mu_{0}\right)^2$ and assign the top $m_1$ to $z_i=1$, and the rest to $0$.